# terminal command execution on startup

Tags: command-line, startup

can you please tell me how can I execute the following command automatically on startup, instead of having to type it manually each time:

```
sudo thinkfan -n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enable the rc.local file by typing

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

After that add every command you want to the following file

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on [zmalltalker.com](http://zmalltalker.com/zlog/thinkfan.html) you have to create a systemd service.

Create a file e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=simple and lightweight fan control program

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/thinkfan -q -n

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable and start the service with

```
sudo systemctl enable thinkfan.service
sudo systemctl start thinkfan.service
```